# Crystal Reports in ASP.NET, language problems?

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a bilingual ASP.NET project that includes a lot of rpt files which are Crystal Reports files. I have never really worked with these kind of things but I should now test that it's possible to deploy these in both languages and so on. By bilingual I mean that these reports should be shown in one of two langauges depending on which language is set in Control Panel. And that works if I run the application in Visual Studio (Debug -> run) but not if I deploy it.

By deploying I mean: project -> copy project, "only files needes to run this application" and copying only these files to iis catalogue. By doing this the reports are shown in language one no matter which of the languages is chosen in Control Panel.

Am I missing something crucial here?

Answer (score 0):

IIS server doesn't use Control Panel language. Older versions of it use system default locale (what is set at OS install phase), newer versions allow set locale (language) in IIS options.

Comment: Hmmm. Ok. But I forgot to mention that if I instead copy all the files from development enviroment to a catalogue instead of the "only files needed to run this application", then the languages pages are shown in, follows the language set in Control Panel, also in web browser. So, that part seems to work as it should?

Comment: Apparently yes - seems that ASP.NET on IIS server can read control panel data. (Does your IIS run under your account or do you log into web server as windows user? Otherwise I can't see, how most control panel settings would apply.) 
For next I would attempt to find culprit file(s) then - I don't have experience with ASP.NET and cannot hint, what files are most likely needed.